# C programming:setlocale/ write to file special characters

Tags: c, scanf, special-characters, setlocale

I write C-program. I whant that my program write to a file special characters like "ÅÄÖ"? I need put answers from user to .txt file. When I use  `scanf` it doesn't work: file "test.txt" contains wrong characters like "™Ž”„††††††" which suppose to be "ÖÄÅöäååå". I work on computer with Windows10.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <locale.h>
 main() {
    char s [30];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "Test: åäö ÅÄÖ\n");   //works fine

    printf("write ÄÅÖ: ");
    scanf("%s",s);        //doesn't work if I pass special chars like ÖÄÅ
    fprintf(fp, s);
    fclose(fp);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: _It doesn't work_: could you be more specific? What is your platform?

Comment: file "test.txt" looks like this:                                                                                          Test: åäö ÅÄÖ
Ž™

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make that clear _there_.

Comment: in the  file "test.txt" i see line nr 1: Test: åäö ÅÄÖ (that's is fine) and in the next line charscters like "™Ž”„††††††" which suppose to be "ÖÄÅöäååå" after i tejped them on screen

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_, not in comments.

Comment: Did you tried open your textfile with another software ? Some notes softwares have sometimes difficulties with UTF-8, and maybe what you did is already working well.

Comment: At least on Linux, the file test.txt looks as it should, containing the Swedish text I put in.

Comment: Extra note: the statement `fprintf(fp, s);` will not do what you want if s contains a percent character.